# Cache flush on synchronized entry ,exit and volatile read and write

Tags: java, synchronized

When synchronized block execution is completed all the processor cache is flushed or only that object on which synchronized statement acted on will be flushed? In the below example when thread finished execution of method2 does data of obj2 is also flushed to the main memory?

```
class cls1 {
    int x=10;
}

class cls2{
    int y=10;
}

class cls3{
    cls1 obj1;
    cls2 obj2;
    public void method2(){
        obj2.y=10;
        synchronized(obj1){
            obj1.x=30;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final cls3 obj3 = new cls3();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                obj3.method2();
            }
        };
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println(obj3.obj1.x);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A happens before relation is established only when the other thread also synchronizes on the lock using which the first thread updated the contents.

[image: Happens before]

In this example Thread B after acquiring the lock on same object M, it will be able to see all the changes that were made before and during the synchronized block. But mind that the lock must be acquired for *happens-before* relationship to occur.

In your  example because `System.out.println(obj3.obj1.x);` is not printed inside a synchronized block, it does not guarantee happens before.

References:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/

EDIT:
Excellent answer by Peter [What is the scope of memory flushed or published to various threads when using volatile and synchronized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035487/what-is-the-scope-of-memory-flushed-or-published-to-various-threads-when-using-v)

Answer (score 4):

> When synchronized block execution is completed all the processor cache is flushed or only that object on which synchronized statement acted on will be flushed?

Quick answer: all of the dirty blocks from the processor cache are flushed.

When a thread enters a `synchronized` block, it crosses a read memory-barrier which causes local copies of memory that have been updated in main memory to be flushed from the local processor memory cache.

When a thread *exits* a `synchronized` block, it crosses a write memory-barrier and all local processor dirty blocks are written to main memory.  That's not just the lock object but *all* dirty memory blocks.

> In the below example when thread finished execution of method2 does data of obj2 is also flushed to the main memory?

Yes.  When the thread exits there is also a write memory barrier that is crossed.

> `System.out.println(obj3.obj1.x);`

This probably will not print `30`.  It is important to realize that:

- There is no guarantee in your code that `thread2` will be running after `thread1` completes.  Even if you start `thread2` after `thread1`, race conditions may have the `thread2` access of `obj1` happen *before* `thread1` updates it or flushes the cache to central memory.
- Also, even if you guarantee that the `thread2` code does run after `thread1` finishes, you will need to make sure that `thread2` crosses a read memory barrier itself to read `obj3` from main-memory and ensure that `thread2` sees the memory updates from `thread1`.  That would mean making `obj3` be `volatile` or having `thread2` also enter a `synchronized` block.

When you are sharing data between 2 threads it is necessary to make sure that you ensure proper order of operations and that the memory synchronization is taken into account.

Comment: CPUs have coherent cache (MESI) between cores that can run threads of the same program, so actually no flushing to main memory happens at all. https://software.rajivprab.com/2018/04/29/myths-programmers-believe-about-cpu-caches/ .   That would be very bad for performance, instead some other level of cache (e.g. L3) is the backstop for coherency traffic, and write-back of modified lines (to L3, or direct transfer to the next core that wants them) only happens when another core does a read or read-for-ownership (as part of a store) to that cache line.

Comment: Thanks for the detail @PeterCordes.  Interesting stuff.  Given how many architectures run Java I don't think that we can say that all CPUs have this cache coherency feature these days (7 years later) but I do think that some edits are in order.  What is interesting about the link is that it acknowledges the nuances of memory synchronization and links to the JSR 133 memory model docs which still use language about flushing to main memory.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we *can* say that; a different programming model is needed for code to communicate between cores that don't maintain cache coherency with each other.  (e.g. MPI using shared memory for message-passing.)  See [When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58535118) (a C++ question, so the answer is never, but it does work in practice, and is what the Linux kernel uses for inter-thread atomics on known compilers (GCC/clang).)  See comments on [Is cache coherency required for memory consistency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76851091)

Comment: There *are* systems with non-coherent cache, like huge clusters (running a different Linux kernel on each node), and e.g. an ARM board with a DSP and microcontroller.  But we don't run threads *of the same process* across different coherency domains.  Not C++ `std::thread`, not Java thread.

Answer (score 2):

JLS doesn't speak about caches and their coherence, it uses 'happens-before' relation to establish ordering of inter-thread actions such as reads and writes to a shared memory. In your example, it's permitted to re-order `obj2.y=10` so it goes after `sync` block. Plus, since there's no 'happens-before' established by method entry/exit, there's no guarantee from JMM that change will become visible after method finishes.

See ["Java memory model"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) of Java spec for detailed explanation of underlying principles.

Btw, seems you forgot to call `start()` method on thread instances you've created in `main`.

Comment: The assignment of `obj2.y=10` cannot be reordered after the `synchronized` block because of the write memory barrier at the end of the block.  See here: http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html

Comment: Also, there is a guarantee that when the write barrier is crossed that any dirty blocks (including `obj2.y`) will be written to main memory.  See the same doc.  You are correct that there is no an order guarantee but there is a memory guarantee.