# Effect of java synchronized monitor enter on non synchronized access or not volatile variables

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, volatile

I have a download operation code that look's like this

```
while(true){
  if(target.flagStop){
    break;
  }else{
    x=target.check();
  }
len=in.read(buff,0,min(BUFFER_SIZE,x));
  out.write(buff,0,len);
  target.position+=len;
}
```

which `flagStop` is a **volatile boolean** 
and `position` is a **non volatile long** value
and inside a `check()` method I have a `synchronized` block

```
long check(){
  //some code here
  synchronized(aLock){
  //some code here
    return something;
  }
}
```

I update(write access) `position` **only** in this thread(only care about this to be exactly have lastest updated) but also some reads from different threads occurs, im my case thease are just for monitoring purposes
so a few bytes lower than I expected it does'nt matter vs than declarimg value as `volatile` which that costs on performance on my main purpose

I know for a CPU instruction to be completed data comes to CPU register after computation progress result will come back to  memory
which
- if that variable declared as `volatile` the result immediately will be written to main memory (not cached anymore)
- otherwise this will be stored in thread cache memory after that in future this value will be written to main memory(write to main memory from cache, time can't be determined (this can be immediately or has a delay no one knows) in my case my question is about this situation that value **is not** `volatile` and **only** in one thread

according to an answer from a dear User in StackOverflow in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39172490/10401124) when we enter a `synchronized` block first of all
***(case 1):*** we have a read operation from main memory (mentioned as read barrier)

and at the end of `synchronized` block
***(case 2):*** we have write operation to main memory (mentioned as write barrier)

I know about ***case 2***
all the modified thread cache variables will be written into main memory
but something that maybe I'm thinking wrong is that in ***case 1:***
we have a read operation from main memory which that overrides thread's cache with  version that stored in main memory.`(main -> cache)`

As I mentioned earlier my `position` value is **not** `volatile` (so have not directly access read/write to main memory use cached value instead) and if I enter to a `synchronized` block which that ***case 1*** occurs (since that possible ,**newer** position value  from thread's cache have not yet have chance to writes its value to main memory) and overrides main memory(possibly older one) version of position into thread cache(i.e. destroy newer one by overriding older value that retrieved by synchronization `monitor enter` operation)
is that really I'm thinking true?
and I must declare `position` as a `volatile` or not?
and tell me if I'm wrong that what's happening in thread cache at `monitor enter`(or ***case 1*** that I mentioned before)
Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Comment: `I also update(write access) position only in this thread` is position accessed anywhere else, including reads?

Comment: `after compution progress result will come back to memory` eh, not really.  It's perfectly valid for a result to be kept in a register and **not** written back into main memory.  `variable declared as volatile the result immediately will be written` "Made visible" is not the same as "written to main memory."  It could be, but it might be dangerous to think this always occurs. `otherwise this will be stored in thread cache memory` **may** be stored, but it's also not 100% guaranteed.  Stuff has a tendency to not be cached randomly and just sort of escape out into the wild when you least expect.

Comment: That explanation you linked to isn't great.  What the specification actually says is that there is a *happens-before* relationship between the *end* of a lock release and the *beginning* of a lock acquire.

Comment: `since that possible ,newer position value from thread's cache have not yet have chance to writes its value to main memory`  I'm not sure what you are trying to say here, but I think the answer is no, nothing bad happens.  That's the trouble with trying to say that a lock acquire creates a read barrier, it doesn't.  Go read the spec.  It says that variables accessed by a single thread are thread safe, period.  No *happens-before* can change that.  As long as only one thread sees `position` you are fine.

Comment: @markspace `is position accessed anywhere else, including reads?`  yes  since main purpose of this variable is in this thread and read from other threads just for  monitoring porposes and in this case I m not sensitive for a few bytes more or less

Comment: If `position` is accessed by some other thread, then you have memory visibility issues.  If you don't care how long an update is delayed, you might be able to tolerate the current code.  However it's usually best to provide memory semantics (i.e. to not have a data race) and use the `volatile` keyword or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of what you are looking for:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.1

> Memory that can be shared between threads is called shared memory or
>   heap memory.
>
> All instance fields, static fields, and array elements are stored in
>   heap memory. In this chapter, we use the term variable to refer to
>   both fields and array elements.
>
> Local variables (§14.4), formal method parameters (§8.4.1), and
>   exception handler parameters (§14.20) are never shared between threads
>   and are unaffected by the memory model.

"Unaffected by" here means that they don't need to be synchronized.  As long as only one thread sees a variable, it's always fine.

This also helps:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.7

> The execution obeys intra-thread consistency.
>
> For each thread t, the actions performed by t in A [actions by that thread] are the same as
>   would be generated by that thread in program-order in isolation, with
>   each write w writing the value V(w), given that each read r sees the
>   value V(W(r)). Values seen by each read are determined by the memory
>   model. The program order given must reflect the program order in which
>   the actions would be performed according to the intra-thread semantics
>   of P.

Actions means both reads and writes.  So your variable `position` is not allowed to be updated with some strange values because of synchronization.  The reads and writes within a single thread of execution happens in the same order as the program statements specify.  The system will not pull strange reads or writes out of cache or main memory out of order.