# Java synchronization and memory visibility. Is 10 visible to other threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, visibility

I have two classes.

One class is just a container for a integer value with get and set synchronized methods.

```
public class Sync {
   private int dataSync;

   public synchronized int getDataSync() {
       return dataSync;
   }

   public synchronized void setDataSync(int data) {
      dataSync = data;
   }
}
```

The other classes is similar.
It is just a container for a integer value with get and set methods without synchronization.

```
public class NotSync {

   private int dataNotSync;

   public int getDataNotSync() {
      return dataNotSync;
   }

   public void setDataNotSync(int data) {
      dataNotSync = data;
   }
}
```

Now my question is "is 10 value guaranteed to be visible to all other threads" at the end of the run method.

```
public class RunSync {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      RunSync rs = new RunSync();
      rs.run();
   }

   private NotSync dataNS;

   private Sync    dataS;

   private int     data;

   public RunSync() {
      dataS = new Sync();
      dataNS = new NotSync();
   }

   public synchronized void run() {
      data = 100;
      dataS.setDataSync(45);
      dataNS.setDataNotSync(10);
      //Question A: is 10 value guaranteed to be visible to all other
      //threads when method exits?
      //we are inside a synchronized block aren't we? 
      //so all writes must be flushed to main memory
   }
}
```

EDIT: Imagine there are other threads. This is just a quickly written example. Question goes to what is exactly guaranteed to flushed back to main memory when a synchronize block finishes.

EDIT2: According to the java memory model
"changes to fields made by one thread are guaranteed to be visible to other threads only under some conditions. One condition is A writing thread releases a sync lock and a reading thread subsequently acquires that same synch lock.

So if another thread acquires the RunSync lock, will it be guaranteed to see 10 in NotSync instance of RunSync? Even though NotSync is not protected?

Edit3: related question without a definitive answer. I am still looking. 
[What is the scope of memory flushed or published to various threads when using volatile and synchronized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035487/what-is-the-scope-of-memory-flushed-or-published-to-various-threads-when-using-v)

EDIT4: To simplify the example what about this method from RunSync class

```
public synchronized void run2() {
    dataNS.setDataNotSync(10);
}
```

When run2 exits, nothing is guaranteed to be flushed to main memory? A definite answer to this will answer my question. If No. that means only members of the lock are guaranteed to be flushed back, and will be visible to other threads provided the other threads acquires that same lock on RunSync.
Answer is No Guarantee.

EDIT5: and in this case, is the assert guaranteed to be true?

```
public class RunSync {

public volatile boolean was10Written = false;

    public synchronized void run2() {
      dataNS.setDataNotSync(10);
      was10Written = true;
   }

   public void insideAnotherThread() {
      if(was10Written) {
         int value = dataNS.getDataNotSync();
         assert value == 10;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why is your question rhetorical?

Comment: It's visible to other threads that synchronize on something before reading it.

Comment: @Matt Timmermans rhetorical because it is just an example. What is exactly flushed back to main memory when synchronize exits? only members of the lock? Not their content?

Comment: If it is a rethorical question, then you don't expect an answer, and then you shouldn't have posted it here in the first place. What are you really asking?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel lol yes my mistake.. confused about the word rethorical. Just checked the meaning oops. Just Yes or No with a short explanation to the question A in the code comment

Comment: I think the phrase the OP is looking for is a theoretical question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, it is not guaranteed to be visible, but it could be. Since the write of 10 is not synchronized there is no happens before ordering with respect to the synchronized read.

> According to the java memory model "changes to fields made by one thread are guaranteed to be visible to other threads only under some conditions.

This is true if the writes of one thread happens before a synchronization action. The write to 10 happens after and as such there is no visibility guarantees.

If, for example, you have a new field and write to it as 10 before you write to `dataSync` (synchronized), and you evaluate dataSync to be 45, then that write to the new field will be visible.

Comment: The actual answer is "maybe", not "no" ;)

Comment: I should say it's not guaranteed to be visible, thank you for the correction :)

Comment: when setDataNotSync exits. I totally agree.

Comment: when synchronize void run() exits?

Comment: Still no because the `synchronized` on run is on a different object reference, `RunSync`. The synchronized write is on `Sync`. Since the read is synchronized on `Sync` you need to create an ordering with respect to that object.

Comment: as a conclusion. what about my EDIT4

Comment: What class is `run2` in, if it's in `RunSync` the answer is still no, it would have to be synchronized on `Sync`

Comment: Yes, that works, though it will work without the `synchronized`. The `volatile` write acts like a `synchronized` write then read. So all the writes prior to the `was10Written` store are said to happen before the read of `was10Written`. What you get is, if `was10Written` is true than  `getDataNotSync` is guaranteed to be 10

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the value 10 in the dataNS.dataNotSync data member in the original code in class RunSync will definitely be visible by any other thread that synchronizes on the rs object, and obtains the lock of rs AFTER the main thread has exited from the rs.run() method. The dataNS.setDataNotSync(10); call is made within a synchronized block (on the object rs), therefore by the JMM, any writes made to any variables made by the main thread right before the release of the rs lock, will be made visible (have happened-before) to any threads subsequently obtaining the lock on rs and then reading those variables.

Notice that any threads that were just sleeping while the main thread made the changes, and then try to read the value of dataNS WITHOUT obtaining the lock on rs, are NOT guaranteed to see the value 10, since there is no happens-before relation established between them reading dataNS and the main thread writing dataNS.

As an example, in the following completed main() method, the thread t1 is guaranteed to print 10, but this is because we start thread t1 AFTER the rs.run() code has executed; if we replaced the order of rs.run(); and t1.start(); the value 10 would be printed only if t1 got the lock AFTER rs.run() got the lock (and finished):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RunSync rs = new RunSync();
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized(rs) {
                System.out.println(rs.dataNS.getDataNotSync());  
            }  
        }
    };
    rs.run();
    t1.start();
}
```

If in the code above we write "t1.start();" and then follow by "rs.run()", in order for t1 to guarantee to print 10, we would need to write a "while(cond) rs.wait()" statement in the run() of our thread that would guarantee that we don't read the dataNS value before rs.run() has finished executing from the main thread, and we would need to call rs.notify() as the last statement of rs.run() method.

Answer (score 0):

What other threads? Anyway you should see the keyword volatile for start. Also synchronizing one method does not synchronize the instance variable for read/write. So If one thread is writing , another one can be reading a different value, since only the methods are synchronized (only one thread at a time is setting the value, and one is reading, but you can have both doing read/write at the same time

Comment: it was a rhetorical question. imagine there are other threads. that was just an example to show case the issue.